# As level computer science paper 2 question

Tags: pseudocode

Could someone help explain the logic of the ms .
The question is
[image]

The RandomChar() module is to be modified so that alphabetic characters are generated
twice as often as numeric characters.
Describe how this might be achieved.

and the marking scheme says
[image]

my logic is that if you randomly generate an integer between 1 and 3 inclusive and multiply that by 3, you would get 3,6,9. Of which only 1/3rd is divisible and you put that as numeric values. And the rest as alphabetic character

Is this right?

Comment: Logic of *milliseconds*? Please don't use images to represent essential text in your posts. Without even mentioning, e.g., *uniform*, `RandomChar()` looks ill defined.

Comment: (`only 1/3rd [of 3,6,9] is divisible` looks as weird as *the marking scheme*)